# Getting the parameter values being passed to SQL database via SQLDataSource control

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, sqldatasource

I am debugging code written by a previous developer :-)

I have a SQLDataSource control that is calling a database stored procedure, and passing quite a large number of paramaters, and the stored proc returns records that populates a gridview control.

When I walk through the code behind to determine the values being passed, is there any way that I can see exactly how the parameters are being formated and passed to the stored proc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SqlDataSource`'s [`Updating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updating.aspx) event for this. It's parameter [`SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourcecommandeventargs.aspx) has a property [`Command`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourcecommandeventargs.command.aspx) that contains the parameters for the query.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to unpick them from Code-behind, use Sql Profiler. If you are using the Express version, there's a Profiler for that too: [AnjLab Sql Profiler](http://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/)

Comment: I am aware of SQL profiler, but not sure how to configure it. I tried looking around on the web, finally gave up. Got any tips regarding profiler? BTW, using the enterprise version of SQL 2005.